# azure app serviceをインターネットからしか接続できないようにしたい

Tags: azure

題名の通りです。
azure app serviceをインターネットからしか接続できないようにしたいです。
そもそもインターネットからしか接続できないようになっているのでしょうか？
そしてapp serviceにアクセスする際認証を設けて自分がアクセスさせたいユーザーしかアクセスさせない予定です。

Comment: 逆に、どこからの接続を制限したいのでしょうか？ Azure はクラウドサービスなので、インターネットからの接続はある意味当たり前な気がします。

Comment: ではapp serviceにアクセスしようと思ったら必ずインターネットを通さないといけないということですかね？

Comment: app  serviceには azure sqldatabaseとの仮想ネットワークがつながっています。それだけです。そこにapp  serviceとの接続をインターネットだけに制限したいです。

Comment: 例えば自分以外がapp serviceにアクセスしようとした際にインターネットじゃないところからアクセスされた場合、セキュリティ的に甘くないですか？設計上は仮想ネットワークで繋がっているSQL databaseだけですが、、、